# Redirect requests to router

Tags: apache, wifi, wamp, router

I have a wireless router and would like to force people who are connected to it to be automatically forwarded to my local Apache(WAMP) install.

So, when people connect to my WI-FI and launch a browser, it shows what I have, they are not able to make an outside connection.

take care,
lee

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is called a captive portal and is implemented in several open source products.  Take a look at:

- Chillispot
- Coova Chilli
- WifiDog
- NoDogSplash
- NoCatSplash

Several open source firmware alternatives come with a captive portal built in.  I know [DD-WRT](http://www.dd-wrt.com/wiki/index.php/Captive_Portal) comes with it out of the box.  [OpenWRT](http://wiki.openwrt.org/doc/howto/wireless.hotspot), [Tomato](http://www.polarcloud.com/tomato/) and others support some sort of captive portal but I'm not sure what the setup looks like.

If you don't need to ever allow people onto the open internet, you could install one of the open source firmwares above and use the firewall to redirect all port 80 traffic to the IP address of your Apache serve.